# What is the closed form of $\int \exp ( \sqrt{x}-x^2)\ dx$?

Tags: closed-form, error-function

My attempt to get the closed form of $\int \exp ( \sqrt{x}-x^2)\ dx$ using integration by part to get something related to error function is failed, I believe that function has a closed form because we can write its form into product of two simple function has closed form such that $\int \exp ( \sqrt{x}-x^2)=\int (exp (-x^2)\times \int(\exp(\sqrt{x})$. We have simply $\int e^\sqrt{x}dx=2\int e^u u\ du=2e^uu-2e^u+C=2e^\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)+C
$ and the first is error function but if we use integration by part with those simple two function it's hard to get that then why ?

Comment: There is no reason to think this integral can be expressed in closed form.  NOTE: the integral of a product is not equal to the product of the integrals.

Comment: According to your hypothesis, $\int 1=\int x\frac 1x=\int x\int\frac 1x$

Comment: @Andrei No, this is not what i meant , I meant if we use integration by part both of tow functions have closed form at a least we get a form en terms of error function

Comment: Have you looked at $2\int e^{u-u^4}udu$?

Answer (score 1):

The expression $$\int \exp ( \sqrt{x}-x^2)=\int (exp (-x^2)\times \int(\exp(\sqrt{x})$$ is not true.

In general integral of product is not product of integrals.

Also there is no reason to expect a closed form for your integral $$\int \exp ( \sqrt{x}-x^2)dx$$ simply because it is  the integral of a product.